# Installing sensu plugins as per ruby version

Tags: ruby, dependencies, gem, sensu

I have `Ruby` `version 2.3` installed and I was looking to install `sensu-plugins-http:6.1.0`
because the latest version was installing another dependency which needs ruby to be on higher version.

Like this I keep getting error for many such dependencies and it take time to figure out which version will work best with ruby 2.3 as many dependencies might need higher version.

Is there a way that I can lookup which version works best with the currently installed `Ruby version` ( for me its 2.3) ?